# v-chip values don't appear after clicking dropdown values and chip close doesn't close

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to get the value for v-chips but I don't know what I changes I need.Also, the X(close) for chip doesn't work too. Would it be good to code in another way?. Help, please and thanks .

This is How It looks.

[Values are not displayed above the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSDjn.png)

[Values are not displayed and chip close doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAKQY.png)

This is the code for HelloWorld.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
     <v-row>
                  <v-col
                    class="d-flex justify-center"
                    cols="6"
                  >
                    <div class="positionButton">
                      <v-btn
                        class="accent-3 blue"
                        dark
                      >
                        Add voice
                      </v-btn>
                    </div>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col
                    class="d-flex justify-center"
                    cols="6"
                  >
                    <VideoPrueba
                      v-for="(step, key) in steps"
                      :key="key"
                      v-model="step.selected"
                      :items="step.options"
                    />
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
                </div>
</template>

<script>
import VideoPrueba from './VideoPrueba'
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    components:{VideoPrueba},
   
    data: () => ({
       steps: [
      {
        title: 'Videos',
        options: ['Video 1', 'Video 2', 'Video 3', 'Video 4'],
        selected: []
      }
    ],
   } )
  }
</script>
```

This is the code for Videoprueba.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
            <span v-for="(el, i) in hey" :key="el.text" class="shrink">
                <v-chip :disabled="loading" close @click="del(el, i)">
                  <v-icon left v-text="el.icon"></v-icon>
                  {{ el.text }}
                </v-chip>
          </span>
    </div>


    <v-tooltip top>
      <template #activator="{on, attrs}">
        <div
          multiple
          v-on="on"
        >

    <v-select
                v-bind="attrs"

      v-model="hey"
      :items="items"
      label="Seleccion video"
      multiple
      return-object
    >



      <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
        <v-chip v-if="hey.length=== 0">
          <span> Seleccion video</span>
        </v-chip>
        
      </template>
    </v-select>
      </div>
      </template>
      <span>Select videos here,please</span>
    </v-tooltip>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "VideoPrueba",

  props: {
    items: {
      type: [Array, Object],
      default: [],
    },
   
  },
  data: () => ({
    hey: "",
    model: {
      prop: "input",
      event: "change",
    },
    
    loading: false,
    selectedItems: [],
  }),
  watch: {
    hey(val){
      console.log('val',val)
      val.map((el, i) => {
        console.log('valor de selecteditems',this.selectedItems)
          console.log('valor de el',el)

        if (!this.selectedItems.includes(el)) {
          console.log('incluido')
          this.selectedItems.push(el);
        } else {
          console.log(el,i)
          //this.selectedItems.push(el);
          this.selectedItems.slice(el, 1);
        }
      });
    }
  },
 
  methods: { 
    del(el, i){      
      console.log(el)
       console.log(i)
       this.selectedItems.splice(i, 1)
    }
  },
  
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because:

1. Your "hey" data is an Array of Strings not Object. "Hey" is not an Object with a property of ".text".
2. You ommitted the :close event for closing the chip - Reference: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-chip/#events-click:close

**Here's the fix you need for both of them**

```
<v-chip :disabled="loading" close @click:close="del(el, i)">
  <v-icon left v-text="el.icon"></v-icon>
  {{ el }}
</v-chip>
```

Cheers

Comment: Hello, Now, the value appears in the v-chip but when I click "X" , It doesn't close , I've modified the code with @click:close="del(el,i)" and nothing happens, I was thinking about putting only "false" instead of "del(el,i) and I get an error  in console.log .Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"    .   I was watching this exercise about closing chips but I'm still thinking how to put it in this case .  https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010

Comment: Dont forget that you declared  `this.selectedItems.splice(i, 1)`
Perhaps you would want to change it to `this.hey.splice(i, 1)`

Comment: It worked, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that. De nada